# powershell replace and delete

Tags: regex, powershell

I need the code to find the string `1234` using the marker `====-`, then replace `####` with the `1234`, then delete the line `====-1234`.

The text file can have one group (Sample Text A):

```
A;1;1;####;19/01/2015;08:45:58;UNKNOWN;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
====-1234
```

Or multiple groups (Sample Text B):

```
A;1;1;####;19/01/2015;08:45:58;UNKNOWN;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
====-1234
A;1;1;####;19/01/2015;08:45:58;UNKNOWN;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
====-5678
```

The code as of right now deletes everything in the text file. Any help?

```powershell
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)(.+?####;
.+?)
====-(\d+)
'@

Get-Childitem -Path C:\somedir -Filter *.txt |
  foreach {

    $text = Get-Content $_ 

    ([regex]::matches($text,$regex) |
      foreach {
        $_.groups[1].value -replace '####',($_.groups[2].value)
      }) -join '' |
      Set-Content $_.FullName
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might benefit from using an `ArrayList` in this scenario. The following approach iterates over the file and notes the positions when either `####` or `====-` are encountered.

It can then modify the contents at those positions by firstly directly replacing the contents at the index where `####` was found, and secondly by using the `removeAt` method of `ArrayList` to delete the entries where `====-` was encountered:

```powershell
[System.Collections.Arraylist]$t = Get-Content .\sampleb.txt
$removeAt = @()

$i = 0
while($i -lt $t.count) {

  if($t[$i] -match "####") {
      $start = $i
  }
  if($t[$i] -match "====-(\d+)") {
      $newval = $t[$start] -replace "####", $matches[1]
      $t[$start] = $newval
      $removeAt += $i
      $start = $i
  }

  $i += 1
}

foreach($idx in ($removeAt | Sort-Object -Descending)) {
    $t.removeAt($idx)
}

$t
```

#### Outputs

```powershell
A;1;1;1234;19/01/2015;08:45:58;UNKNOWN;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
A;1;1;5678;19/01/2015;08:45:58;UNKNOWN;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
B;0;0;0;319.95;
B;0;0;0;319.89;
```

This does assume your file is consistent and that `====-` **always** follows `####` and the two are balanced. Extra logic is otherwise required to account for that.

Comment: great thanks. yes they are always going to be '====-' and '####'. i am creating this txt file and picked those markers. Now i need this to edit multiple files in the same directory and override the file. Possible?

Comment: Of course. Different question though so you should really ask a new one and show where you're getting stuck. You'd just need to get all the files, loop over them and run that code for each, and write `$t` back out to the current file name

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a continuation of an earlier question I had provided an answer to, but that solution relied on using the -Raw parameter of Get-Content and you're apparently running V2.  Beyond that the posted data has changed from the original question, so that solution wouldn't have worked anyway.

Here's an updated version, adjusted for the new data criteria and compatible with V2:

```
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)(.+?####;.+?
.+?)
====-(\d+)
'@

$Files = 
Get-Childitem -Path C:\somedir -Filter *.txt 

foreach ($file in $files)
 {
    $Text = Get-Content $file.fullname | out-string 

    ([regex]::matches($text,$regex) |
    foreach {
    $_.groups[1].value -replace '####',($_.groups[2].value)
    }) -join '' |
    Set-Content $file.fullname
 }
```